# YA dystopia: girl with high-ranking father leaves the city with an outsider boy

Tags: story-identification

I read a YA dystopian style book at least a few years ago and I can only recall vague details:

1. Girl is running on a virtual treadmill in her room alone, I believe towards the beginning of the book.
2. Society in this world may have valued lack of contact with other humans.
3. Girls father was high ranking.
4. Girl meets an outsider boy, who tries to resist liking her.
5. They go to some sort of underground dance club.
6. Boy takes her away from her city to an outsider location.
7. I believe the girl was important to the boy's group due to the access she could get them to her city because of father's ranking in her society.
8. I recall reading this book when it was the only one in the series, but the book felt like it was going to have a second in the series...don't know if that happened or not.

What book is this?

Comment: Edited it to be easier to read. Do you also remember any details about when you read it, when it was released, or what country and language you read it in?

Comment: I know it's been at least 3 years since I read it.  I don't know when it was released.  I believe it was released in the U.S.A and it was written in English.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the answer for myself....the book is Awaken by Katie Kacvinsky and the trilogy is now complete, so I can finish the series.  :)

Comment: I'm glad you found it. This answer would be improved by you elaborating on how this book matches what you were looking for. Also, you should accept the answer by clicking on the check mark under its score.

Answer (score 0):

Is it Delerium by Lauren Oliver? It sounded like Matched by Ally Condie vaguely also but it's been a long time since I read it

Comment: You have a good start on an answer, but you need to explain why you feel the answer fits (optionally, also link to a site like Goodreads and/or provide a cover image). Also, unless you feel that they're combining the details of two similar works (happens more often than you might think), it's best to post them as separate answers.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I read Delirium and while it does have some similarities to the book I'm searching for, it isn't the right one.  I've also read Matched by Condie and that isn't it either, but definitely a good series from the genre.  :)